# Equivalence of an expression in C

Tags: c

This is an assignment and a question for measuring basic knowledge on C. 
It is part of a course on Coursera.org. But, this is just to measure if you are able to do the course. This is just a copy-paste of the actual question.
I did great on all other question, I just don't seem to get the following one :

Suppose you are compiling for a 32-bit platform and sizeof(int) == 4. Which one of the following is equivalent to c[b] if c is of type int* and b is of type int?

Possible answers:

```
-1 * b[c]
*(c+b)
none of the above
*c+b
c[b][0]
```

What I am asking is, what the right answer is from the above possibilities, and why? 
I mean what logic does one use to arrive at the result? What should I read to understand the procedure to get there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*(c+b)
```

This is equivalent to `c[b]` .

According to C99 standard -

> 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>
> Constraints
>
> 1.One of the expressions shall have type ''pointer to complete object type'', the other expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ''type''.
>
> Semantics
>
> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just shown another question, whose answer clarified me. Did not know about this a[b] == *(a + b) . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
*(c+b)
```

It is known as **Pointer Arithmetic**.

Comment: Awesome ... i was just shown another question that clarified everything to me with this single expression a[b] == *(a + b)